# Sammy.js + ASP.NET MVC overloaded controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sammy.js

While trying out some example with Sammy.js and ASP.NET MVC 3 , i have found that
Sammy.js does not support overloaded controller method call.

please refer below code :

```
(function($) {

    var app = $.sammy('#main', function() {

      this.get('#/Home/Posts', function(context) {
        context.log('Retrieve all posts');
      });

      this.get('#/Home/Posts/:id', function(context) {
        context.log('Retrieve post by id');
      });

    });

    $(function() {
      app.run('#/');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

When I try to use single method in controller (i.e. Without overloading it works fine)
but after overloading the method sammy.js script does not respond.

Has anyone got a workaround to deal with this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the second action to

```
this.get('#/Home/Post/:id', function(context) {
    context.log('Retrieve post by id');
});
```

Comment: for that i have to create new action with name Post which should work... but i dont want to create new action with different name.